# Use Voice Remote for Google TV with Android TV

Tags: remote-control, android-tv, bluetooth-pairing, google-tv

I paired the `Voice Remote for Google TV` with an `Android TV` succesfully, and all functions work. Except for powering on the TV when it is off. This makes sense because I suspect that the Bluetooth chip is disabled when the TV is in standby.

Since the `Voice Remote for Google TV` is capable of sending infrared signals, this should be very easy to solve. But I can't figure out how.

Maybe I can pair the remote to somebody elses `Google TV` and setup the infrared function for the powerbutton? But I suspect that when pairing it back to the `Android TV` afterwards, it will also clear the infrared preference stored on the remote in the process.

Does anyone know a solution for this? Because there is no technical reason this cannot be done, it's just that `Android TV` doesnt provide the setup menu.

Comment: You lack clarity on what exactly you are doing. Is it that you have the Google Chromecast (the HDMI part) **AND** the remote? _OR_ just the remote that you've paired through Bluetooth to the TV? The **wake signals can only be sent through wifi** or if the HDMI part of the Google Chromecast device is connected to the TV. The remote talks to that HDMI part which in turn turns on the TV.

Comment: No, I don't have a Chromecast. I have a TV with Googles Android TV OS (and ofcourse these have Chromecast build-in, so it would not make sense to connect an external HDMI dongle to it). I also have a Google Voice Remote (which have infra-red build-in). My only question is how to setup the infra-red on Android TV OS. Since that is very easy to do on Google TV OS, and as both OS'es are virtually the same under the hood, I expect there must be a way. There are also tricks to upgrade Android TV to Google TV, which will solve the problem. But as the TV is brand new I dont want to void the warranty.